# Merge [addons] with [browser-addons]?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Given the nature of this SE, is the [addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addons) tag referring to something else than browsers?

I think not and thus the two tags ([browser-addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-addons) and [addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addons)) should be merged.

What do you think?

Comment: browser-addons tag is now the parent tag

Comment: @phwd Put it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[browser-addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-addons) tag is now the parent tag and [addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addons) is a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think we should merge them into browser-addons (it'll be easier to tag). Then we could see if there are questions about add-on that is not "browser add-on".